# AS3 Vimeo API: Any way to stop forward scrubbing of unviewed video?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

Does anyone know of a way to prevent a user from scrubbing forward into unviewed video using the AS3 Vimeo API? Basically I want to make it so the viewer can review parts of a tutorial already seen, but can't jump ahead.

I was able to target the VideoScrubberView object and it's children, but I'm not sure how to override the behavior.

Comment: So you have your scrubber right? You just need a variable that keeps a record of Amount Played. Seeking backwards should not change this value (only playing ahead, a check will be needed to confirm). Link the track area width (clickable MC for seeking) to the Amount Played. Just the general logic. You should show your seeking code so its easier for others to help.

Comment: It's actually not my scrubber, but Vimeo's. I'm trying to avoid building my own scrubber that mimics theirs (though I might have to). Setting up logic similar to yours, I was able to get it so the scrubber would jump back to the furthest point played by tracking the play progress and reading the seek to seconds when the scrubber is released, but I'm not sure how make it so the scrubber can't move beyond that point when it is dragged. Unfortunately, the Vimeo API doesn't have a listener for the scrubber position as the user is interacting with it. So I get nothing until it is released.

Comment: Just flying through to say I'll try knock up some sample code for such scrubber before morning (8pm round here). For now you could try placing a rectangle block (converted to MovieClip) on the scrubber but its starting X position is linked to the maximum seek point. Now they cant "scrub" by clicking where the blocking MC is (to look nice you can give it zero opacity so its invisible to the eye but still does its job).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but when I tested what would happen if you grabbed the scrubber and drug over an invisible button/blocker it doesn't release the scrubber. The scrubber stays stuck to the mouse position. I tried decompiling a vimeo SWF to check out the LoopyAPI class and other (couldn't find online) to see if I could hook into the existing functionality but I see a lot of private/protected functions so that probably wouldn't work.

Comment: You're very close. The Blocker should be a MovieClip object. On the blocker add an event listener for MOUSE_OVER like `MC_blocker.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, stopDragging);` then have a function such as `function stopDragging (evt:MouseEvent) : void { stopDrag(); }` .. In that stopDragging function you want either `stopDrag();` or `e.currentTarget.stopDrag();`.. I can't remember off the top of my head right now.

Comment: Thanks again for your insight! Unfortunately, this didn't work. I tried stopDrag(); e.currentTarget.stopDrag(); e.target.stopDrag(); I'm going to dig around in the decompiled class, but I suspect they aren't using a startDrag at all. I think they are just detecting the mouse position over the scrubber.

Comment: See com\vimeo\moogaloop\views\videoControls\VideoScrubberView.as in the [decompiled code](http://dev.brianvargish.com/vimeo.zip). They're tracking mouseX with internal functions. Seems like I'll have to make my own scrubber unless I can extend or over ride this class.

Comment: What I'm doing at this point is setting VideoScrubberView's children at 3 and 5 to mouseEnabled = false and mouseChildren = false to disable the original scrubbing functions, and using my own code to emulate the original functionality. At least I can control the original UI components with code so I don't have to create that stuff.